# change width of tbody when the scrollbar not shown

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I have table with scrollbar , when I filter table, scrollbar unshown, this is good for me, but the problem that width of  is changing, and bigget from width of table.
it is look like this:

1. with scrollbar:
   [image]
2. without scrollbar, after filter:

[image]

this is my css code:

```
.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100% !important;
}


tbody {
 display: block;
 height: 326px;
 overflow: auto;
 width: 1205px;
}

thead, tbody tfoot, tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed; /* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}

thead {
   table-layout: fixed;
}

.table tr th:nth-child(1), .table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30px !important;
}

.table tr th:nth-child(2), .table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 90px !important;
 }

.table tr th:nth-child(3), .table tr td:nth-child(3) {
   width: 100px !important;
 }

 .table tr th:nth-child(4), .table tr td:nth-child(4) {
   width: 90px !important;
 }

 .table tr th:nth-child(5), .table tr td:nth-child(5) {
     width: 90px !important;
 }

 .table tr th:nth-child(6), .table tr td:nth-child(6) {
     width: 90px !important;
 }

 .table tr th:nth-child(7), .table tr td:nth-child(7) {
     width: 85px !important;
 }

 .table tr th:nth-child(8), .table tr td:nth-child(8) {
     width: 90px !important;
 }

 .table tr th:nth-child(9), .table tr td:nth-child(9) {
     width: 110px !important;
 }

.table tr th:nth-child(10), .table tr td:nth-child(10) {
    width: 95px !important;
}
```

How resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure your elements don't shift around when a scroll bar appears then use `scrollbar-gutter:stable` on the element that the overflow attribute is applied to.  See below.

scrollbar-gutter on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter)

```css
.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100% !important;  
}

tbody {
 display: block;
 height: 100px;
 overflow: auto;
 width: 1205px;
  
 /* added this */
 scrollbar-gutter: stable;
}

thead, tbody tfoot, tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed; /* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}

thead {
   table-layout: fixed;
}

.table tr th:nth-child(1), .table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30px !important;
}

.table tr th:nth-child(2), .table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 90px !important;
 }

.table tr th:nth-child(3), .table tr td:nth-child(3) {
   width: 100px !important;
 }

 .table tr th:nth-child(4), .table tr td:nth-child(4) {
   width: 90px !important;
 }

 .table tr th:nth-child(5), .table tr td:nth-child(5) {
     width: 90px !important;
 }

 .table tr th:nth-child(6), .table tr td:nth-child(6) {
     width: 90px !important;
 }

 .table tr th:nth-child(7), .table tr td:nth-child(7) {
     width: 85px !important;
 }

 .table tr th:nth-child(8), .table tr td:nth-child(8) {
     width: 90px !important;
 }

 .table tr th:nth-child(9), .table tr td:nth-child(9) {
     width: 110px !important;
 }

.table tr th:nth-child(10), .table tr td:nth-child(10) {
    width: 95px !important;
}
```

```html
<table class='table'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A01</td>
      <td>AAA02</td>
      <td>AAA03</td>
      <td>AAA04</td>
      <td>AAA05</td>
      <td>AAA06</td>
      <td>AAA07</td>
      <td>AAA08</td>
      <td>AAA09</td>
      <td>AAA10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A01</td>
      <td>AAA02</td>
      <td>AAA03</td>
      <td>AAA04</td>
      <td>AAA05</td>
      <td>AAA06</td>
      <td>AAA07</td>
      <td>AAA08</td>
      <td>AAA09</td>
      <td>AAA10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A01</td>
      <td>AAA02</td>
      <td>AAA03</td>
      <td>AAA04</td>
      <td>AAA05</td>
      <td>AAA06</td>
      <td>AAA07</td>
      <td>AAA08</td>
      <td>AAA09</td>
      <td>AAA10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A01</td>
      <td>AAA02</td>
      <td>AAA03</td>
      <td>AAA04</td>
      <td>AAA05</td>
      <td>AAA06</td>
      <td>AAA07</td>
      <td>AAA08</td>
      <td>AAA09</td>
      <td>AAA10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A01</td>
      <td>AAA02</td>
      <td>AAA03</td>
      <td>AAA04</td>
      <td>AAA05</td>
      <td>AAA06</td>
      <td>AAA07</td>
      <td>AAA08</td>
      <td>AAA09</td>
      <td>AAA10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>No scroll bar</p>
<table class='table'>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>A01</td>
    <td>AAA02</td>
    <td>AAA03</td>
    <td>AAA04</td>
    <td>AAA05</td>
    <td>AAA06</td>
    <td>AAA07</td>
    <td>AAA08</td>
    <td>AAA09</td>
    <td>AAA10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A01</td>
    <td>AAA02</td>
    <td>AAA03</td>
    <td>AAA04</td>
    <td>AAA05</td>
    <td>AAA06</td>
    <td>AAA07</td>
    <td>AAA08</td>
    <td>AAA09</td>
    <td>AAA10</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I try, but it is be error: "validation (CSS 4.0): 'scrollbar-gutter' is not known CSS property name".

Comment: What are you using to validate your CSS? Looks like it's not supported on Safari either. https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_scrollbar-gutter